# How to play audio file from background in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to build an ***alarm clock app***, so it needs to ***play sound according to the time*** that was entered in the DatePicker(NSDate)W. Well I've done that by implementing NSTimer that is executing play audio function. I've also provided that with setting *AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback* and *Background Modes* in info.plist to allow playing sound even if the user will take an app to the background. And it works perfect, but only if an app is in a foreground(timer cannot execute code from background). What is the way of making that?
P.S. One guy told me that he has done that before by playing 'silent sound' to keep an app in executing state. Hope that there can be much better solutions =)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class AlarmViewController: UIViewController {

var date = NSDate()
var ding = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setting AVAudioSession to enable playing music in silent mode
        do {
            _ = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            _ = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Something wrong in declaring session")
        }

    let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5), interval: 0, target: self, selector: "prepareAudios", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func prepareAudios() {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Hills", ofType: "m4r")

    do {
        ding = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    } catch {
        print("Something wrong in prepareAudios() func")
    }

    // This code sets max volume on device
        let masterVolumeSlider = MPVolumeView()

        if let view = masterVolumeSlider.subviews.first as? UISlider{

            view.value = 1.0

        }

    ding.volume = 1.0

    ding.prepareToPlay()

    ding.play()
}
```

Comment: Try to use NSNotification, it will replace nsTimer.

Comment: Please check http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Comment: @aBilal17 Thanks, but if the user enable silent mode on the device the sound will not play i guess

Comment: yes in that case you can not open sound forcefully.

Comment: @aBilal17 Noticed that using of AVAudioPlayer is required in my situation, it also need to play sound longer than just 30 sec